# Can I install USB 3.0 USB bracket and header if my motherboard does not support USB 3.0?

Tags: usb, desktop-computer, hardware-rec, case

I have Gigabyte [GA-H61M-S](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S-rev-10/sp#sp) motherboard and it does not support USB 3.0.

My computer case has USB and Audio module but, its not working anymore. So, I am thinking to replace it with a good quality panel.

Now, I have found [this](https://www.amazon.in/Neon-Front-Panel-Connector-Adapter/dp/B073P4N21N/ref=pd_sbs_147_3/259-5822732-6957312?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B073P4N21N&pd_rd_r=13b75391-9d54-4dc9-b32f-bca5e1967ae5&pd_rd_w=zc4dW&pd_rd_wg=op5m8&pf_rd_p=fbf43daf-8fb3-47b5-9deb-ae9cce3969a9&pf_rd_r=M97ZDB2PY3ACQ8ABCHP4&psc=1&refRID=M97ZDB2PY3ACQ8ABCHP4) one product which meets my requirement. I have to connect it to USB header on motherboard. But, it says its for USB 3.0.

So, my question is whether this panel will work or not with my motherboard. I know that if it works then it will give me speed of USB 2.0 only but, will it work at all or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the panel only needs a standard USB 3.0 header connection, then yes, you can buy an adapter to connect it to a USB 2.0 header. The result should be exactly the same as if connecting a 3.0 extension cable to a 2.0 port or vice versa – all of the 3.0 extra pins will remain unconnected, and devices will work in USB 2.0 mode.

However, the available power will also be limited to what USB 2.0 normally provides, and that might not be enough for all ports to work.

It would be better to buy a [PCI-Express card with a USB 3.0](https://www.google.com/search?q=pcie+usb+3.0) controller – some of them have an internal USB 3.0 pin header (or even two) in addition to the standard external ports.

Answer (score -1):

Just keep in mind though that you may not be able to boot off these USB 3.0 ports as BIOS/UEFI will not have firmware to make it available to be used as a boot device.